# Condition number of a $2\times 2$ square block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a general rule to relate the condition number of the $2\times2$ square block matrix
$
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
C & D\\
\end{array}\right),
$
where the matrices have the following sizes:

- $A$: $n\times{n}$
- $B$: $n\times{m}$
- $C$: $m\times{n}$
- $D$: $m\times{m}$

If not, what I'm actually after is the following, more specific case; $
\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
B^T & 0\\
\end{array}\right),
$
where $A$ is symmetric, such that the block matrix is also symmetric. I couldn't find any properties of the condition number that would help, neither did writing out the definition...